# How to train BertForMaskedLM using Huggingface Trainer?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to continue pre-training of BERT model on my own dataset. As far as I understood, this is called *domain-adaptation*. So, this will be an unsupervised approach.
I will use `BertForMaskedLM` or `BertForPreTraining`.  How can I achieve this using `transformers.Trainer`? What should my `Dataset` class return in `__getitem__` method? I could not find any resource about this specifically. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend you to take a look at this HuggingFace Transformers notebook example of ["How to fine-tune a model for common downstream tasks"](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/transformers_doc/custom_datasets.ipynb).

It's quite well explained and it will help you a lot as guidance.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. Furthermore, the link is dead. I think this is where the original content is hosted:
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.16.2/en/custom_datasets
But it isn't really all that helpful.